# NodeJS image not uploading and category name showing variable instead of value

Tags: node.js, multer

I am working on a NodeJS style blog and for some reason, the variable for the category name shows up as #{category.name} whereas the other variable values actually show the values. Secondly, When I submit the image for the post, it does not upload the image. Any help to see if there might be some errors in my code would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

[image: screenshot of variable in place of value]
[image: screenshot of dev tools error]

app.js

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var favicon = require("serve-favicon");
var logger = require("morgan");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var session = require("express-session");
var multer = require("multer");
var upload = multer({ dest: "./public/images" });
var expressValidator = require("express-validator");

var mongo = require("mongodb");
var db = require("monk")("localhost/nodeblog");

var routes = require("./routes/index");
var posts = require("./routes/posts");
var categories = require("./routes/categories");

var app = express();

app.locals.moment = require("moment");

app.locals.truncateText = function(text, length) {
  var truncatedText = text.substring(0, length);
  return truncatedText;
};

// view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "pug");

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

// Express Session
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "secret",
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
  })
);

// Express Validator
app.use(
  expressValidator({
    errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split("."),
        root = namespace.shift(),
        formParam = root;

      while (namespace.length) {
        formParam += "[" + namespace.shift() + "]";
      }
      return {
        param: formParam,
        msg: msg,
        value: value
      };
    }
  })
);

// Connect-Flash
app.use(require("connect-flash")());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require("express-messages")(req, res);
  next();
});

// Make our db accessible to our router
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.db = db;
  next();
});

app.use("/", routes);
app.use("/posts", posts);
app.use("/categories", categories);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error("Not Found");
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get("env") === "development") {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render("error", {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render("error", {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

index.pug

```
extends layout

block content
  if posts
   each post, i in posts
    .post
     h1
      a(href='/posts/show/#{post._id}')
       =post.title
     p.meta Posted in 
      a(href='/categories/show/#{post.category}') #{post.category} by #{post.author} on #{moment(post.date).format("MM-DD-YYYY")}
     img(src='/images/#{post.mainimage}')
     !=truncateText(post.body,400)
     a.more(href='/posts/show/#{post._id}') Read More
```

addpost.pug

```
extends layout

block content
    h1=title
    ul.errors
        if errors
            each error, i in errors
                li.alert.alert-danger #{error.msg}
    form(method='post', action='/posts/add', enctype="multipart/form-data")
        .form-group
            label Title:
            input.form-control(name='title', type='text')
        .form-group
            label Category
            select.form-control(name='category')
                each category, i in categories
                    option(value='#{category.name}') #{category.name}
        .form-group
            label Body
            textarea.form-control(name='body', id='body')
        .form-group
            label Main Image:
            input.form-control(name='mainimage', type='file')
        .form-group
            label Author:
            select.form-control(name='author')
                option(value='Erik Robles') Erik Robles
                option(value='John Doe') John Doe
        input.btn.btn-default(name='submit',type='submit',value='Save')
        script(src='/ckeditor/ckeditor.js')
        script
            | CKEDITOR.replace('body');
```

addcategory.pug

```
extends layout

block content
    h1=title
    ul.errors
        if errors
            each error, i in errors
                li.alert.alert-danger #{error.msg}
    form(method='post', action='/categories/add')
        .form-group
            label Name:
            input.form-control(name='name', type='text')
        input.btn.btn-default(name='submit',type='submit',value='Save')
```

posts.js

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var multer = require("multer");
var upload = multer({ dest: "./public/images" });
var mongo = require("mongodb");
var db = require("monk")("localhost/nodeblog");

router.get("/add", function(req, res, next) {
  var categories = db.get("categories");

  categories.find({}, {}, function(err, categories) {
    res.render("addpost", {
      title: "Add Post",
      categories: categories
    });
  });
});

router.post("/add", upload.single("mainimage"), function(req, res, next) {
  // Get Form Values
  var title = req.body.title;
  var category = req.body.category;
  var body = req.body.body;
  var author = req.body.author;
  var date = new Date();

  // Check Image Upload
  if (req.file) {
    var mainimage = req.file.filename;
  } else {
    var mainimage = "noimage.jpg";
  }

  // Form Validation
  req.checkBody("title", "Title field is required").notEmpty();
  req.checkBody("body", "Body field is required").notEmpty();

  // Check Errors
  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors) {
    res.render("addpost", {
      errors: errors
    });
  } else {
    var posts = db.get("posts");
    posts.insert(
      {
        title: title,
        body: body,
        category: category,
        date: date,
        author: author,
        mainimage: mainimage
      },
      function(err, post) {
        if (err) {
          res.send(err);
        } else {
          req.flash("success", "Post Added");
          res.location("/");
          res.redirect("/");
        }
      }
    );
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

index.js

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var mongo = require("mongodb");
var db = require("monk")("localhost/nodeblog");

/* GET home page. */
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  var db = req.db;
  var posts = db.get("posts");
  posts.find({}, {}, function(err, posts) {
    res.render("index", { posts: posts });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

categories.js

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var mongo = require("mongodb");
var db = require("monk")("localhost/nodeblog");

router.get("/show/:category", function(req, res, next) {
  var posts = db.get("posts");

  posts.find({ category: req.params.category }, {}, function(err, posts) {
    res.render("index", {
      title: req.params.category,
      posts: posts
    });
  });
});

router.get("/add", function(req, res, next) {
  res.render("addcategory", {
    title: "Add Category"
  });
});

router.post("/add", function(req, res, next) {
  // Get Form Values
  var name = req.body.name;

  // Form Validation
  req.checkBody("name", "Name field is required").notEmpty();

  // Check Errors
  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors) {
    res.render("addpost", {
      errors: errors
    });
  } else {
    var categories = db.get("categories");
    categories.insert(
      {
        name: name
      },
      function(err, post) {
        if (err) {
          res.send(err);
        } else {
          req.flash("success", "Category Added");
          res.location("/");
          res.redirect("/");
        }
      }
    );
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

If I am missing anything, please let me know so I can make the appropriate edits. Again, Thank you.
P.S. By structure is:

```
routes
 categores.js
 index.js
 posts.js
views
 addcategory.pug
 addpost.pug
 error.pug
 index.pug
 layout.pug
app.js
```

Comment: multer is storing uploads in `uploads/`, not seeing how its serving it from `/images`

Comment: Hello Lawrence. Thank you for your comment. Even after changing the code to ./public/images in the app.js, I am still getting the same result. Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I not used pug, but I think you would do: `img(src='/images/' + post.mainimage)` else it be a string.

Comment: Lawrence, Thank you so much. That took care of the image issue. Now I just need to fix the variable not showing the value. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The code I was using is old (circa 2016) and no longer works. In calling the variable name, you must remove the curly braces, hash and quotes from the first option variable. Here is how the code should read in the categories options section:
**addpost.pug**

```
.form-group
    label Category
    select.form-control(name='category')
        each category, i in categories
            option(value=category.name) #{category.name}
```

I hope this answer helps someone struggling with the same issue.